# Are there any potential risks with recursive partial views to render a tree structure in a Razor view

Tags: recursion, razor, memory-management, tree

**My question**

*My question is not on how to do the following (rendering a tree structure with Razor views), which I have found many answers to. My questions are about the underlying memory management and potential risks of a given solution:*

My solution so far is (what I have also found as a common solution out there)   to use a (Razor) partial view (or similar) and call it recursively. But is the use of recursion over an unknown number of nodes (meaning an unknown number of nested loops and method calls) a risk free (or good) solution?

My questions are:

- Are there any potential memory management risks (risks for Stack Overflow, extreme loading times or request time-outs etc.) when the number of nodes and child nodes are uncertain?
- If so, Is there a better solution?

The differing scenarios would look something like the following:

- Max depth of tree: 5
- Subtrees/ child nodes of any node will reach from approx 0 ~ 40 nodes

*_LocationTreeRowPartial.csthml*

```
<ul>
    <li>

        // Some code like name of node etc.

        @foreach (var row in Model.Children)
        {
            @Html.Partial("PartialViews/_LocationTreeRowPartial", row)
        }

    </li>
</ul>
```